# AWS Glue error when reading S3 Partitioned Table into DynamicFrame

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a partitioned dataset in S3 that one of my AWS Glue crawlers has registered into the catalog.
[image: Glue Catalog]

[image: S3 Structure]

So far so good. Then I try to read all partitions of this table into a single DynamicFrame like so (Python), in my dev endpoint (hid the names):

```
>>> data = gc.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database='database_name', table_name='table_name')
```

This seems to work, but I cannot do anything with this frame, not even printSchema(). It appears that it could not load all of the S3 partitions correctly, and throws the following when trying to printSchema or convert to a Spark DataFrame:

```
[Stage 11:>                                                         (0 + 3) / 3]18/04/13 16:58:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 64, ip-172-31-50-57.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 4): com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FatalException: Unable to parse file: xxx_xxx_20170430.txt
```

I know in regular pyspark, reading nested partitions (folder structure) is annoying and you have to union them together if you want a single dataframe. I thought DynamicFrames would handle this when reading from the catalog since it has all the metadata to where the partitions are. Is there something else I'm missing?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any results if you run a query against the data in Athena?

How about after you use Athena to 'load partitions'?

Comment: @RobinL yeah, Spark was fine too. i found out that this was due to Glue not liking any encoding except UTF-8. some of these partitions were ISO-8859-1. when i run 'iconv' to convert to UTF-8 and upload it back to S3, Glue is happy again. 

hopefully just a matter of time before Glue allows other encodings :)